# jQuery UI radio button - how to correctly switch checked state

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, radio-button

I have a set of radio buttons, all styled with jQuery UI's `.button()`.

I want to change their checked state. However, when I do so programatically on the container's change event with:

```
$("#myradio [value=1]").attr("checked", false);
$("#myradio [value=2]").attr("checked", true);
```

The values are changed correctly, but the UI styling still shows the unchecked radio button with the checked style, and the checked one still looks unchecked.

I looked through the jQuery UI documentation on the `button()` method for radio buttons, but there is nothing about how to change the state and update the UI styling.

The nutshell of the problem is that calling the `$("selector").button("disable");` code does not change the button's active state - the underlying radio button is correctly checked, but the UI active state does not change. So, I get a greyed out button that looks like it's still checked, and the real selected button appears unchecked.

**Solution**

```
$("selector").button("enable").button("refresh");
```

Comment: Antony, I tried it and the button("enable") doesn't work for me. Shouldn't be like *$("selector").attr('checked', true).button("refresh");* ?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to call the [`refresh`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#method-refresh) method after changing the underlying state:

> Refreshes the visual state of the button. Useful for updating button state after the native element's checked or disabled state is changed programatically.

**Working example: http://jsbin.com/udowo3**

```
function setRadio(id) {
    var radio = $('#' + id);
    radio[0].checked = true;
    radio.button("refresh");
}
```

That uses IDs for the radios, but it doesn't matter as long as you get a jQuery instance containing the relevant `input[type=radio]` element.

Comment: Worked - thank you! Why do I need to do this? Is this a bug or bad behaviour in jQuery UI?

Comment: @Antony: Well, there's no reliable, cross-browser event thrown when the state of the `checked` or `disabled` properties is changed. What surprises me is that they're not using CSS to have the browser handle the change automatically, but I expect they have a reason (IE6 support, perhaps -- IE6 doesn't do state selectors on anything but links). The other surprise was that they don't provide a method that you can use to change the `checked` state and update the UI all at once. Still, easy enough once you know. :-)

Comment: Hey guys, when I use the 'refresh' call, I get the following error - Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'. 
Have you guys seen this / know why I am getting this error?

Comment: I got the same error as @Blake and @Coder also. Turns out I'm using jQuery Mobile not jQuery UI. I was able to get it to refresh using `.checkboxradio("refresh")` instead of `.button("refresh")`

Answer (score 18):

Despite posts to the contrary, you CAN reference a radio button by ID. Not sure why JQuery UI doesn't refresh the buttons automatically when checked, but you do it like this:

```
$('selector').attr('checked','checked').button("refresh");
```

Working example:

```
<div id = "buttons">
 <label for="b1">button1</label>
 <label for="b2">button2</label>
 <label for="b3">button3</label>

 <input type="radio" name = "groupa" id = "b1" value="b1">
 <input type="radio" name = "groupa" id = "b2" value="b2">
 <input type="radio" name = "groupa" id = "b3" value="b3">
</div>

<script>
  $('#buttons input').button();     
  $('#b3').prop('checked', true).button("refresh");
</script>
```

Comment: My only addition here would be to use 'prop' instead of 'attr' thereby making it $('selector').prop("checked",true).button("refresh").

Comment: When I try this fix, I get the following error - Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh' 
Does anyone know what could cause this?

Answer (score 2):

If someone is still getting this issue, make use of:

```
.prop('checked',true);
```

instead of:

```
.attr("checked", true);
```

Comment: Thank you. Even with button("refresh"), it didn't work reliably with attr. prop seems much better.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [code](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.button.js#L121), you need to toggle the `ui-state-active` class, but the simplest way is probably just `$('someradiobutton').trigger('click')` (or if you don't want your custom event handlers to run, `$('someradiobutton').trigger('click.button')`).

Comment: -1: This will not work with `jQuery UI button`s (which the question is about) as they create separate elements not connected to the original radio button. You need to call `button("refresh")` after changing the button state (preferably with `prop('checked', boolvalue)`)

Answer (score 1):

Will reset all radio buttons but you can get more specific with the selector.

```
$( 'input:radio' )
     .removeAttr('checked')
     .removeAttr('selected')
     .button("refresh");
```

Comment: -1: This will not work with `jQuery UI button`s (which the question is about) as they create separate elements not connected to the original radio button. You need to call `button("refresh")` after changing the button state (preferably with `prop('checked', boolvalue)`)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by completely resetting the Buttonset with setTimeout.

Add a click Event to the Radio Button that needs Confirmation.
Please note the clicked 'radioButton' and the complete 'radioSet' in the Code below:

```
$('#radioButton').click(function(){
    if(confirm('Confirm Text') != true){
       resetButtonset('#radioSet', 200);
       return false;
    };
});
```

Create a handy Function that resets your Buttonset:

```
function resetButtonset(name, time){
    setTimeout(function(){$(name).buttonset();}, time);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input:radio[name="radioname"] + label[for="eglabel"]').click();
```

Thats all.

Comment: -1: This will not work with `jQuery UI button`s (which the question is about) as they create separate elements not connected to the original radio button. You need to call `button("refresh")` after changing the button state (preferably with `prop('checked', boolvalue)`)